# Given p1=P(X1>X2), p2=P(X1=X2) and p3=P(X1<X2) (with necessarily p1+p2+p3=1), what is λ1 and λ2？

Tags: pr.probability, geometric-probability, poisson-distribution

In the following three equations : p1, p2, p3 are known, find λ1=? , λ2=?

(with necessarily p1+p2+p3=1)

$$ p_1 = \sum_{0 \leq k_2 \lt k_1 \in Z}(\frac {\lambda _1^{k_1}} {k_1!}\cdot{e^{-\lambda _1}})(\frac {\lambda _2^{k_2}} {k_2!}\cdot{e^{-\lambda _2}}) $$

$$ p_2 = \sum_{0 \leq k_2 = k_1 \in Z}(\frac {\lambda _1^{k_1}} {k_1!}\cdot{e^{-\lambda _1}})(\frac {\lambda _2^{k_2}} {k_2!}\cdot{e^{-\lambda _2}}) $$

$$ p_3 = \sum_{0 \leq k_1 \lt k_2 \in Z}(\frac {\lambda _1^{k_1}} {k_1!}\cdot{e^{-\lambda _1}})(\frac {\lambda _2^{k_2}} {k_2!}\cdot{e^{-\lambda _2}}) $$

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: These innocent looking equalities are more interesting in the following context: Let $X_1,X_2$ be independent, $Po(\lambda_1), Po(\lambda_2)$-distributed random variables. Given $p_1 = \mathbb{P}(X_1 > X_2)$, $p_2 = \mathbb{P}(X_1 = X_2)$ and $p_3 = \mathbb{P}(X_1 < X_2)$ (with necessarily $p_1+p_2+p_3 = 1$), what is $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. Of course similar questions are possible for other discrete distributions as well.

Comment: @DieterKadelka Your statement is more appropriate, do you have a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Gang Huizou: Unfortunately no immediate solution. Of course for given $p_1, p_2, p_3$ you can it solve numerically. If I find non numerical solution I will tell you.

Comment: @DieterKadelka
Thank you, I have not done mathematics for many years, and I have recently rekindled my interest, so my level is relatively poor. 

If p1, p2, and p3 are given, how can I get the numerical solution? If you can, please tell me how to get the numerical solution, and then I will find a way to get the non-numerical solution